# dockerized express app : npm-debug show only in portainer

Tags: node.js, nodemon, npm-debug

I have a dockerized express application (using nodemon) which is composed of an interface (/ui) and on API (/api).
I want to debug all my app with [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) using `chrome inspect` or NIM to view the `debug` outputs.

My problem is that in the chrome inspector I can see the `console.log()` but not the `debug` outputs. Both appear in the `docker logs`.
On Portainer the logs are separated into Stdout and Stderr and `debugs` appear in Stderr.

How can I visualize `debug` ouputs in Chrome inspector ?

Ports binding :

```
  ports:
    - 5004:3000  //express port (http://{ip}:5004/ui or http://{ip}:5004/api)
    - 50041:9229 //view log in chrome inspector
```

Running command :

```js
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"
  },
```

## Tried

- `DEBUG` is already set in the container
- Defining `localStorage.DEBUG = "*:*"` on Chrome
  [image]

Comment: `"dev": "DEBUG=\"*:*\" nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"` - https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#environment-variables

Comment: in browser set: `localStorage.DEBUG = "*:*"` - https://github.com/visionmedia/debug#browser-support

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I tried it but I still have the same issue.